# PHP subtraction in a while loop for graph

Tags: php, math, while-loop

I have this code:

```
$previous = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $difference = $row['steam'] - $previous;
            $strXML .= "<set name='".date("G:i:s", strtotime($row["tstamp"])).  "' value='".$difference."' color='AFD8F8' />";
            $previous = $row['steam'];
        }
```

This code is working great with every result after the first one. If i can explain, $previous starts at 0, so the first block on the bar chart actually comes out at 3334, as 3334 - 0 = 3334, however from then on i get exactly what i want because its doing the math between real values. how can i fix the first result?

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `$difference` before the while (if it is relevant)?

Comment: difference doesnt exist before the loop :)

Comment: What do you intend `$difference` to be for the initial value? That is, the difference between `$row['steam']` and what?

Comment: And which value would be expected as the first one? Difference with the last row?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure, thats what i'm asking for advice on, would it be better to retrieve another value from the table (mysql) to set an intial value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're graphing the changes in values, wouldn't it make more sense to skip the first value?  I put a code sample below.

I'm not sure exactly what value you would want for the first run through the loop otherwise.

```
$previous = 0;
$firstRun = true;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $difference = $row['steam'] - $previous;
        if (!$firstRun)
          $strXML .= "<set name='".date("G:i:s", strtotime($row["tstamp"])).  "' value='".$difference."' color='AFD8F8' />";
        $previous = $row['steam'];
        $firstRun = false;
    }
```

Comment: That works for me, so i'm showing 9 instead of 10 but at least there's not a massive bar at the start of the graph throwing all of the axis out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your application logic. Giving an alternative to Sam's answer, if `$difference` is not set yet, you can set it zero.

```
$difference = isset($difference) ? $row['steam'] - $previous : 0;
```